# Rotate object in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to Three.js. I would like to create a 2 cube and 2 text over cubes and rotate it. I have done with it but in wrong rotation.

my code is:

```
function render() {

    var delta = Math.random() * (0.02 + 0.02) + speed;

    cubeGroup.rotation.x -= cubeGroup.rotation.x+delta;
    cubeGroup.rotation.y += delta + 0.02;
    cubeGroup.rotation.z -= 0.02;

    textGroup.rotation.x -= textGroup.rotation.x+delta;
    textGroup.rotation.y -= delta + 0.02;
    textGroup.rotation.z += 0.02;


    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

but it rotates in wrong directions.
my expected result should be like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/3ov9jVJhbH2jwzGxk4/giphy.gif)

The result I am getting is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/6912/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The result I am getting isExample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/6912/).

Comment: How to rotate the cubes as in this gif(https://media.giphy.com/media/3ov9jVJhbH2jwzGxk4/giphy.gif)

Comment: So you want to rotate the cubes such that with the point of rotation is between them?